# Android remote file browser for Ubuntu, graphical

Tags: gratis, android, file-management, ubuntu, remote-access

From Ubuntu Linux, I want to quickly find and download any file present on my Android device, and in particular pictures.

Requirements:

- Runs on Ubuntu
- Graphical interface with pictures thumbnails (must)
- Free, ideally open source
- Does not require anything software on the Android side, except developer options
- Connects via USB (WiFi is OK too)

Comment: I would only know something matching all your requirements if you'd drop the "picture preview" condition. If that's acceptable as "until something better turns up", let me know – but I bet you already know what I'm pointing at :)

Comment: Selecting a picture using thumbnails would be the main use case, so for this question I prefer to keep it as a strict requirement.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that much – which is why I only put a comment. Sadly, without installing an app on the 'droid, I'm not aware of any such solution. And you know, that's exactly my area of expertise. Still, open to learn about it – maybe something new popped up recently :) Good luck!